# Python dynamic attributes creation, a blessing or a curse?

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
>>> class Foo():
        pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.a = 'test'
>>> foo.a
'test'
```

One can just override `__setattr__` to make attributes read only and prevent their creation at runtime, however:

- Why is this the *default* Python behavior (any good reasons)?
- Is there any practice to prevent this without altering each class?
- Would you worry about this behavior in serious projects? don't you consider it error prone? or you can just ignore it (relying on new IDEs code completion)

Comment: What other default behaviour would you expect, and what consequences would it have for class definitions, in particular `__init__`?

Comment: @delnan I would expect `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'a'` consequences may be in typing, you can for example type: foo.pasword = 'something' instead of foo.password = 'something'

Comment: @01walid: What delnan means is that there is no difference between `self.a = 'test'` in the `__init__` method and `foo.a` on the instance. Both `self` and `foo` are just references to the instance.

Comment: Ok but, at least -for me- in `__init__` you're still inside the class declaring its attributes, I'm asking why the same behavior *outside* the class definition as for an instance of it?

Comment: @01walid: You can define the `__init__` *outside* the class and then add a reference to it to the class; it'll work just the same as if it was part of the class definition. Python is a *highly dynamic* language.

Comment: ... of course, this could be changed - but this would make function definitions inside the class special. Special cases are generally bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others already mentioned, preventing this would require a special case for `__init__`, and one of the design principles of Python is to avoid special cases, see the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

This design is also in line with other design decisions, e.g, the lack of static type checking or access control modifiers. Python tends to empower its users, not to enforce things.

You can easily prevent this for any particular class by using [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). However, there is no way to change this *globally*.

While this can in theory cause errors, I wouldn't worry about it much. For example, a typo could mean that you are by accident create a new attribute when you meant to assign to an existing attribute. However, good unit testing coverage will usually catch this.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you worry about this behavior in serious projects? don't you
>   consider it error prone? or you can just ignore it (relying on new
>   IDEs code completion)

Yes, I worry. To me, it is not clear from the post whether you are pointing to the dangers of allowing outsiders to reason about and change the structure of the objects, or to the dangers of assigning to a previously undefined attribute. However, both behaviors are known to be problematic (the first, for sacrificing the benefits information hiding techniques bring to the table and relying on convention; the latter for allowing the spreading of definitions of structure/object when it is desired to have them locally organized).